# Netbeans not showing line number with error

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-platform

In my Netbeans, I am getting a red exclamation mark along with the file name that we usually get when there is something wrong in the code. At the same time it shows a red exclamation mark on the line number where the possible error is. My Netbeans is showing the mark besides the file name but not identifying the line number with error. What could be wrong?

Comment: Happens to me occasionally, I know neither the cause nor the solution. But when it does happen I just close Netbeans and reopen it again; wait a little bit and I can see the erroneous line number marked.